# Selenium move_to_element().perform() cannot move cursor

Tags: python, selenium

[the website i am using](https://tabelog.com/en/rstLst/2/?maxLat=34.7109&minLat=34.6459&maxLon=135.5177&minLon=135.47260000000006&lat=34.678399999999996&lon=135.49514999999997&zoom=13)

i want to use selenium to scroll down this web page, however the website is split into two screens which left side is a list of result, right side is a map.

In order to scroll left side down to bottom, the cursor have to be within result area.

So i tried perform() here, the xpath is pointing to one of the result, but it is not working:

```
hover = ActionChains(driver);
Elem_to_hover = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js-map-search-result-list"]/li[1]/p/a/img""");
hover.move_to_element(Elem_to_hover);
hover.perform();
```

**So selenium is not able to use perform() when there are multiple same elements in the page?**

Then i tried to use the xpath pointing to the result display area, but still not working

```
hover = ActionChains(driver);
Elem_to_hover = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js-map-search-result-list"]""");
hover.move_to_element(Elem_to_hover);
hover.perform();
```

Comment: Make sure element is visible before calling the method `Elem_to_hover = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js-map-search-result-list"]"""); `

Comment: tried and still no luck

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("js-item-count-upside")).click();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='js-map-search-result-list']/li[1]/p/a/img"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", element);
```